# What are tokens in elasticsearch for exactly?

Tags: elasticsearch

I googled for my question, but couldn't find an answer. I'm fairly new to elasticsearch and I think I didn't get the idea about tokens yet.

I've built a mapping with a custom name_analyzer that uses the filters lowercase, unique and asciifolding with preserve_original=true.

I have the field search_combo_name and the content for example is this:

```
André, André Mustermann, andre.mustermann@gmail.com, Mustermann
```

When I use kibana to analyze the string above against my name_analyzer, I get the following result:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "andre",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "andré",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "mustermann",
      "start_offset" : 13,
      "end_offset" : 23,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "andre.mustermann",
      "start_offset" : 25,
      "end_offset" : 41,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "gmail.com",
      "start_offset" : 42,
      "end_offset" : 51,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 3
    }
  ]
}
```

That's the result I expect, but what are these tokens used for?
When I search with bool must/should or match, elasticsearch searches for the content of the fields and not the tokens, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These tokens are the ones that are going to be indexed and that you can then search on.

All queries will run on those tokens (i.e. **not on the raw content directly**), which is why it is important to set proper field types and analyzers (in case of `text` fields) when indexing data into Elasticsearch.

Failing to do so can result in bad relevance (and also bad performance), i.e. queries with bad and/or imprecise results, or queries that take too long to execute. It's a very wide topic, but maybe if you present your use case in more details, we can help better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
My search works now as intended, but maybe you can help with one more thing:

I had to map firstname and lastname as keywords, because I want to sort by these fields., but analyzers can't be used with keyword fields. So I created a normalizer for them which uses the filters lowercase and asciifolding.
When I use ```"query": { "bool": { "should": { "wildcard": { "firstname": { "value": { "andre*" } } } } } }``` it gives "André Mustermann" as result.
That's what I want, but why is that? Why does e matches é in this case?

Comment: `e` matches `é` because of the `asciifolding` normalizer. Feel free to ask another question regarding this specific case if needed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The search works as I want now. :)